# Netty+NIOdatagramChannel+Multicast+Protobuf

Tags: netty, protocol-buffers

I am getting UnsupportedOperationException when i do datagramChannel.joinGroup(multicastAddress, networkInterface); Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. I am trying to join a multicast group using NiodatagramChannel. I dont want to use OioDatagramChannel.
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     at         org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.example.qotm.MulticastReceiver.run(MulticastReceiver.java:36)
    at io.netty.example.qotm.MulticastReceiver.main(MulticastReceiver.java:51)

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ConnectionlessBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.DatagramChannel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.DatagramChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelFactory;

public class MulticastReceiver {
private static ConnectionlessBootstrap connectionlessBootstrap;
public void run() {
    DatagramChannelFactory datagramChannelFactory = new   NioDatagramChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    connectionlessBootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(
            datagramChannelFactory);
    connectionlessBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ServerPipelineFactory());
    connectionlessBootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", "reuseAddress");

    DatagramChannel datagramChannel = (DatagramChannel) connectionlessBootstrap
            .bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));
    InetSocketAddress multicastAddress = new InetSocketAddress("224.2.2.3",
            8888);
    NetworkInterface networkInterface;
    try {
        networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress
                .getByName("224.2.2.3"));
        datagramChannel.joinGroup(multicastAddress, networkInterface);
        // datagramChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("239.195.255.255",
        // 8888));
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: It will be great if someone can share the example with another approach but netty is must

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: Thanks Norman for looking into this, Please find the complete stracktracke below Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:337)
 at io.netty.example.qotm.MulticastReceiver.run(MulticastReceiver.java:36)
 at io.netty.example.qotm.MulticastReceiver.main(MulticastReceiver.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is only support when using java 7+ . Seems like you are using an earlier version. I will improve the error message to make it more clear what the cause.

Comment: Hi, I am using Java 1.7 but still getting the same error. Please help